# How do I understand the memory of GTX980M, 4GB or 8GB?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I have just bought a new laptop, which is advertised as **GTX980M 8G**.

So I checked:
[image]
[image]

[image]

dxdiag is saying "memory available is roughly 4GB."

[image]

2 of them are saying it's a graphic card with 4G, and the other two are saying it's 8GB.

Can someone help me understand this?

```
http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-980m/specifications
```

does not really say anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AIDA64 and GPU-Z are ok. The [Dxdiag report is a known bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2026022/) for Windows 7. Report the CPU-Z issue to the creator of the tool.

Comment: Never knew that dxdiag had such a problem! Thanks!

Comment: What confuses me here is that GPU-Z is showing a clock speed of 540, is that right? Does not sound right to me...

Comment: @Probst modern GPUs have power saving settings to lower clock speed and the Voltage.

Comment: It shows the same for both GPU clock and default clock though, my GPUs show their maximum clock as the default clock and a lower clock for the GPU clock when they clock down. I have all AMD GPUs though, is this a difference between AMD and Nvidia?

Comment: @Probst maybe. I don't have a nVIDIA so I can't test this

Comment: @Probst Do you think the GPU clock is too slow or too fast? I will check these too later. Thanks for raising this!

Comment: I would have expected a much higher clock, the desktop GTX 980 is clocked at something like 1200. I am not really sure what the mobile 980 is supposed to be clocked at though so this could be normal but it just seems really strange since most GPUs these days seem to have clocks around 1000 or higher.